# Ошибка дериктории при написании бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot

````
import config
from telebot import types 
import random

from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN, threaded=False)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    sti = open('static/welcome.webp' , 'rb')
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)

    # keyboard
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Рандомное число")
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Как дела?")

    markup.add(item1, item1)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}! \nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, бот созданный чтобы быть подопытным кроликом.".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_echo(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Рандомное число':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(random.randint(0,1000000)))
        elif message.text == 'Как дела?':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отлично, сам как?')
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я не знаю что ответить ')
# RUN
bot.polling( none_stop = True )```





**Вот ошибка:
sti = open('static/welcome.webp' , 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'static/welcome.webp'**
````

Comment: Почему у вас на 2 и на 5 строке одинаковый текст, это так нужно?

Comment: Ошибка заключается в том, что бот не смог найти файл к которому вы обращяетесь, попробуйте без него, поверте, это вам сохранит милион нервов=)